# How to get _id of inserted object in mongodb mongoose with addToSet

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Using `addToSet` with mongoose, how do I get back the newly inserted id of the object.  In this example the `_id` of the friend added to the friends collection.  Friend is defined in the model as having an `_id` field.

```
db.user.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $addToSet: { friends: {name:"bob"} } }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

addToSet() will adds an object to an array. So if I understand your question correctly, this might work:

```
db.user.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $addToSet: { friends: {name:"bob"} } },
   { new: true}
).exec( (err, user) => {
    user.friends // an array
    var bob = user.friends.filter( x => x.name == "bob");
    bob._id
})
```

Comment: that would only work if the set was empty to begin with - but would need to support the case if there are already items in the set.

Comment: right, then you need to query the array too.. let me update my answer

Comment: ah, I see, you are right,  I don't know if current version of mongodb can do update and aggregate at the same time. perhaps you could just filter the returned array